# Flex AdvancedDataGrid dataChangeRequest

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

Can anyone give me an example of the use of the dataChangeRequest Style on the AdvancedDataGrid, I can't seem to get it working. I'm trying to make the cell of the item flash when the dataProvider is updated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AdvancedDataGrid has some problems detecting when a dataProvider is updated/changed. I have run into this problem many times. The bug is documented by Adobe here:

http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FLEXDMV-1334?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Many others have come across this problem as well. Here is a possible solution:
http://www.joshuaostrom.com/2008/09/18/advanceddatagrid-adventures-in-binding/

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: That's certainly very interesting. Thanks for pointing it out.